# Multi-line and spanned rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

found a solution for a problem with multi-line headers.

```
import pandas

headers = [
    ('data1', 'value1'),
    ('data1', 'value2'),
    ('data2', 'value1'),
    ('data2', 'value2'),
    ('data3', 'value1'),
    ('data3', 'value2'),
    ('data4', 'value1'),
    ('data4', 'value2'),
]

data = [
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
    (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18),
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(headers))
```

[multiheaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RvGC.png)

I don't understand how to add multilines

[multirows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alEI5.png)

I tried to transpose and add new multi-line headers - nothing happened. does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create horizontal multiindex the same way as columns, but using `index` argument of `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas

headers = [
    ('data1', 'value1'),
    ('data1', 'value2'),
    ('data2', 'value1'),
    ('data2', 'value2'),
    ('data3', 'value1'),
    ('data3', 'value2'),
    ('data4', 'value1'),
    ('data4', 'value2'),
]

index = [
    ('key1', 'val1'),
    ('key1', 'val2')
]

data = [
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
    (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18),
]


df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(headers),
    index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
)
df
```

Output:

```
           data1         data2         data3         data4       
          value1 value2 value1 value2 value1 value2 value1 value2
key1 val1      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8
     val2     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18
```